# JBoss application complete path

Tags: java, jboss, contextpath

Is there any way I can get url address of an application from java code, I mean complete address not only value from getContextPath(). Something like http://localhost:8080/etc

Answer (score 0):

Try with [getRequestUrl()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()).

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

In a servlet or JSP, you can call `javax.servlet.http.HttpUtils.getRequestURL(request)`

It returns a StringBuffer containing the entire URL up to the servlet

From the javadoc

> Reconstructs the URL the client used to make the request, using information in the HttpServletRequest object. The returned URL contains a protocol, server name, port number, and server path, but it does not include query string parameters.

If you only want up to the context path, you'll have to remove your servlet path

Answer (score 0):

There is no method that returns the entire URL including the query parameters.  You need to use something like:

```
req.getRequestURL()+"?"+req.getQueryString();
```

Or if you don't have query parameters you can use `getRequestURL`

It is pretty confusing, but here is a graphic that helps sort it out:

[image: relationship of different methods]